# Cannot install mayvai after uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda due to conflicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder, mayavi

[Snapshot of the error that I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8GpJ.png)

I uninstalled and reinstalled Anconda python 2.7, but when I am trying to do conda install mayavi, I see unsatisfiable error.Conflicts in bottleneck, mayavi and navigator-updator. Also tried doing pip install mayavi, it did not work. Kindly help!

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: I just created Python2.7 env and mayavi seems to install without any issues. I am using Mac. Note it seems to downgrade my qt and pyqt installations

Answer (score 3):

mayavi package seems to have issues with many standard conda packages raising multiple conflicts.

Create new conda environment where you install mayavi, activate it and install mayavi in it.

```
conda create --name <your env name> python=2
source activate <your env name>
conda install mayavi
```